# Exporting data to Excel

Tags: export, core-language

I wrote two while loops to compute some data groups and to export each in XLS format to a file . I want to export each file with a generated name like FtPr0 or Ftr0P. Let us suppose my value for `P` is 50 and `r0 = 10`, then I want to export the file Ft5010.XLS or Ft1050.XLS. I tried string, string-join and many other similar operations, but I was unable to export my data correctly.

How can I fixe my code to perform the export correctly?

```
k1 = 1;
n2 = 5;
While[k1 <= n2, 
  r0 = 10*k1;
  j = 1;
  n1 = 5;
  While[j < n1, 
    P = 50*j;
    q[z_] := r0 + P z + P*15*z^3;
    Ft = List[];
    For[i = 0, i <= 21, i++, 
      z = N[1*10^-6 + i*5*10^-8];
      F = q[z];
      AppendTo[Ft, {z, F}]];
    (*Export["  Ft.xls", Ft,"XLS"];SystemOpen["  Ft.xls"]*)
    Export["Ft" <> ToString[P] <> "file.xls", Ft, "XLS"];
    j = j + 1]; 
    n2 = n2 + 1]
```

Comment: I made two change and it worked fine for me.  First, I changed the last line to `k1=k1+1` to stop the loop.  I suppose `n2 = n2-1` would also do it.  Then I changed the export to `Export["Ft" <> ToString[P] <> ToString[r0] <> ".xls", Ft, "XLS"];`  That gave me 20 files.

Answer (score 5):

The `Table[]` command lets us avoid `While` and `For` loops.  Here is a simpler way to export your data to one XLS file with multiple worksheets.  First, we create a list of worksheet names that contain the values of P and r0

```
 wkshts = Flatten[
  Table["P " <> ToString[50 j] <> ";r0 " <> ToString[10 k1],
   {j, 4}, {k1, 5}], 1];
```

The above `Table` command along with `Flatten` gives us 20 worksheet names for our 4 values of P and 5 values of r0.  Next, we generate our data.  We need 20 sets of data.  Each set has 21 rows and 2 columns.  We can do it with one `Table` along with `Flatten`

```
data = Flatten[Table[
    N[{z, 10 k1 + P z + P*15*z^3} /. z -> ((5 i/100) + 1)/10^6 /. 
      P -> 50 j, 10],
    {j, 4}, {k1, 5}, {i, 21}], 1];
```

We could check that the dimensions are correct with `Dimensions[data]`.  Now we export the data with this command

```
Export["Ft.xls", Sequence[Thread[wkshts -> data]]]
```

The result is one XLS file with 20 worksheets.  Make sure the data is correct before using it.

This same approach could be used to generate 20 files names and write the 20 sets to them.  Using `Table` can be much cleaner than using `While` and `For`.